# gradle import local jar with transivite dependency

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have two jars which are in local $projectDir/lib/a.jar, b.jar , i need to add these two jars in my gradle build which also includes the transitive dependency of a and b jar

My gradle build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.test.c'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
    url = file('lib')
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    compile('com.test.a:a:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT')
    compile('com.test.b:b:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a `maven()` repository you will need to store your jars using the [maven repository layout](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+Layout+-+Final) conventions

Eg

```
$projectDir/lib/com/test/a/a/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/a-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
$projectDir/lib/com/test/a/a/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/a-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
$projectDir/lib/com/test/b/b/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/b-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
$projectDir/lib/com/test/b/b/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/b-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

Etc